# No sound on Ubuntu 20.04.4 running from Acer CB3-111 Chromebook (GNAWTY)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

My audio refuses to load, even if I do all of the fancy instructions on other things.

```
 aplay -l
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 1: chtmax98090 [chtmax98090], device 0: 1 []
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 1: chtmax98090 [chtmax98090], device 1: Deep-Buffer Audio (*) []
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```